# Concatenate $(this) to string in jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, concatenation

I'm trying concatenate $(this) to string in jquery selector as shown below but my code doesn't seem to work:

```
    // when td is clicked
    $("body").on("click", "td" ,function() {

        if ( $(this + ' > .td_inputs').is(':hidden') ) {
            // 
        } 

    });
```

What is wrong in above code?

Comment: Provide us with the your HTML markup (table)

Comment: You can't concatenate `this` which is an object with a string. Not clear what you are trying to accomplish without relevant html sample and a better explanation. Please see [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jQuery `this` references to DOM element.

If you would like to check in jQuery way if `.td_inputs` (which is child of `td`) is hidden, then you should use `.children()` method:

```
// when td is clicked
$("body").on("click", "td" ,function() {

    if ( $(this).children('.td_inputs').is(':hidden') ) {
        // 
    } 

});
```

Comment: `this` is NOT an event object. It is a dom element

Comment: @charlietfl right! To fast answer! Will change that.

Answer (score 1):

The general format you're looking for, to reuse `this` is:

```
$("> .td_inputs", this)...
```

or

```
$(this).find("> .td_inputs")...
```

In OP's case, as you're using `>` you can use `.children` directly without the `>`, eg

```
$(this).children(".td_inputs")...
```